# How to stop events from being sent to output

Tags: logstash

I'm new to logstash and I'm trying to find a way to log nginx events. I don't want log all access events but only log 404 events, so I tried something like this:

My current configuration looks like this

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    host => "localhost"
  }
}
filter {
  if [fields][type] == "nginx" {
    if [fields][category] == "access" {
      grok {
        match => { "message" => ["%{IPORHOST:[nginx][access][remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[nginx][access][user_name]} \[%{HTTPDATE:[nginx][access][time]}\] \"%{WORD:[nginx][access][method]} %{DATA:[nginx][access][url]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[nginx][access][http_version]}\" %{NUMBER:[nginx][access][response_code]} %{NUMBER:[nginx][access][body_sent][bytes]} \"%{DATA:[nginx][access][referrer]}\" \"%{DATA:[nginx][access][agent]}\""] }
        remove_field => "message"
      }

      if "404" != [nginx][access][response_code] {
        drop {}
      } 
    }
  }
}

output {
  lumberjack {
    hosts => ["listener.logz.io"]
    port => 5006
    ssl_certificate => "/usr/share/logstash/keys/TrustExternalCARoot.crt"
    codec => "json_lines"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the drop doesn't work at all. I have been trying to debug this but the logs doesn't show much useful thing. I event tried to move the drop outside of the if but all events are still being logged.

---

Answer below:

So my issues were that:
1. I did not fully understand how filebeat and logstash work
2. I looked at the example code from an older version

In the newer versions, the extra fields passed in filebeat will be pushed under the "fields" key. In addition to that, I had fields_under_root: true in my configuration without knowing what it really does.

So I removed the key fields_under_root: true in my filebeat configuration, then everything works because now the if in the filter actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    host => "localhost"
  }
}

output {
  if "404" != [nginx][access][response_code] {
    lumberjack {
      hosts => ["listener.logz.io"]
      port => 5006
      ssl_certificate => "/usr/share/logstash/keys/TrustExternalCARoot.crt"
      codec => "json_lines"
    }
}
}
```

By the way you can debug Logstash configuration with: (for Logstash 5.1+)

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --config.test_and_exit -f <the config file/folder>
```

EDIT:

if it doesn't work, try to add this filter between input and output:

```
    filter {
      if [fileset][module] == "apache2" {
         if [fileset][name] == "access" {
            grok {
                    match => { "message" => ["%{IPORHOST:[apache2][access][remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[apache2][access][user_name]} \[%{HTTPDATE:[apache2][access][time]}\] \"%{WORD:[apache2][access][method]} %{DATA:[apache2][access][url]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[apache2][access][http_version]}\" %{NUMBER:[apache2][access][response_code]} %{NUMBER:[apache2][access][body_sent][bytes]}( \"%{DATA:[apache2][access][referrer]}\")?( \"%{DATA:[apache2][access][agent]}\")?",
                      "%{IPORHOST:[apache2][access][remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[apache2][access][user_name]} \\[%{HTTPDATE:[apache2][access][time]}\\] \"-\" %{NUMBER:[apache2][access][response_code]} -" ] }
                  }
    }
  }
}
```

The reason is that perhaps if you don't do it then you can't access the [nginx][access][response_code].

This actually should work.

Comment: oh nice, so you put the if at the output instead. Then that makes we wonder what is the purpose of the drop filter? Perhaps I misunderstand how it is supposed to work?

Comment: That is just another way to do it.

Comment: Hello, I will mark your answer as accepted. My issue was something else (which I will edit the question to describe it), but your answer did lead me to finding the issue.